# dplyr package: How can I query large data frame using like '%xyz%' SQL syntax?

Tags: r, dplyr

dplyr is the only package that can handle my 843k data.frame and query it in a fast way.
I can filter fine using some math and equal criteria, however I need to implement a search for a concept.

I need something like this sqldf query

```
library(sqldf)
head(iris)
sqldf("select * from iris where lower(Species) like '%nica%'")
```

In dplyr help I was not able to find how I could do it. something like:

```
filter(iris,Species like '%something%')
```

The starting and ending % is very important. Also, note that the data frame has 800+k rows so traditional R functions may run slow. It has to bee a dplyr based solution.

Comment: `dplyr is the only package that can handle my 843k data.frame` - I highly suggest the R package `data.table`.

Comment: I made a decision to focus on dplyr syntax and "skip data.table" My whole app is commited to dplyr so data.table solution is OK but native dplyr is best. I think dplyr IS using data.table under the hood.

Comment: `dplyr` can work with data tables, but unless you explicitly load `data.table` and convert your data.frames to data.tables, it won't use it under the hood. Doing so might give you additional speed gains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this -

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
filter(iris, grepl("nica",Species))
```

EDIT: Another option - the function `%like%` in `data.table()`

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
##
Iris <- iris[
  rep(seq_len(nrow(iris)),each=5000),
  ]
dim(Iris)
[1] 750000      5
##
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
##
Dt <- data.table(Iris)
setkeyv(Dt,cols="Species")
##
foo <- function(){
  subI <- filter(Iris, grepl("nica",Species))
}
##
foo2 <- function(){
  subI <- Dt[Species %like% "nica"]
}
##
foo3 <- function(){
  subI <- filter(Iris, Species %like% "nica")
}
Res <- microbenchmark(
  foo(),foo2(),foo3(),
  times=100L)
##
> Res
Unit: milliseconds
   expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
  foo() 114.31080 122.12303 131.15523 136.33254 214.0405   100
 foo2()  23.00508  30.33685  39.77843  41.49121 129.9125   100
 foo3()  18.84933  22.47958  29.39228  35.96649 114.4389   100
```

Comment: This is great. So in conclusion, dplyr is the fastest. and final answer is: filter(Iris, Species %like% "nica"). How can I find help for the %like% function in data.table?

Comment: Yes I believe so - although, as I noted, I'm not an expert with `data.table` and I have a feeling that `foo2()` is doing a vector scan rather than a binary search, so there could be a faster way. Regardless, using `filter` with `%like%` as in `foo3()` seems reasonably fast. (After `library(data.table)`, if you're using RStudio you can type `%like%` in the help pages search bar, or from your console type `?"%like%"`.

Comment: %like% is in fact just a wrapper for grepl so sticking with just grepl may be the simplest

Answer (score 3):

full code would be (including the lowercase)

```
require(data.table)
iris %>% filter(tolower(Species) %like% 'nica')
```