# What is the R equivalent of SQL's "LIKE '%searched_word%'"?

Tags: sql, r

How would I check if a particular word is contained in the text of a field in my dataset using R.

In SQL, we can use the LIKE comparison operator. For example,

```
SELECT * FROM schools WHERE name LIKE '%Public School%'
```

If I had to do the same thing in R, how would I do that?

Comment: I had no idea, so I did a google search on "r pattern matching".  The results looked promising.

Comment: Suggestion for title: `What is the R equivalent of SQL's like '%searched_word%'?`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given

```
schools <- data.frame(rank = 1:20, 
                 name = rep(c("X Public School", "Y Private School"), 10))
```

try this:

```
subset(schools, grepl("Public School", name))
```

or this:

```
schools[ grep("Public School", schools$name), ]
```

or this:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT * FROM schools WHERE name LIKE '%Public School%'")
```

or this:

```
library(data.table)
data.table(schools)[ grep("Public School", name) ]
```

or this:

```
library(dplyr)
schools %>% filter(grepl("Public School", name))
```

Comment: `data.table` has a `%like%` operator, no need for `grep` => `schools[name %like% "Public School"]` & if you use a `tbl_dt` you can even do `schools %>% filter(name %like% "Public School")` with `dplyr`

Comment: The setkey of data.table could make searching much faster.

Comment: [Related: dplyr package: How can I query large data frame using like '%xyz%' SQL syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892529/dplyr-package-how-can-i-query-large-data-frame-using-like-xyz-sql-syntax/24892863#24892863)

Answer (score 0):

In Base R one can use %in% to subset data e.g. dataframe[dataframe$variable %in% dataframe2$variable2]

Comment: The `%in%` is an exact match and I believe that the OP wants an approximate match or a search for terms within a string.

Answer (score 0):

The `qdap` package has a convenience wrapper for `agrep` that allows you to search all fields in a data frame or specific fields:

```
schools <- data.frame(
    rank = 1:20, 
    schools = rep(c("X Public School", "Y Private School"), 10)
)


library(qdap)
Search(schools, "Public School", "schools")

##    rank         schools
## 1     1 X Public School
## 3     3 X Public School
## 5     5 X Public School
## 7     7 X Public School
## 9     9 X Public School
## 11   11 X Public School
## 13   13 X Public School
## 15   15 X Public School
## 17   17 X Public School
## 19   19 X Public School
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following might answer the question in a simple way.

its a merge of the %in% and %like% function

```
'%inlike%'<-function(namevec1,namevec2){
  temp1<-strsplit(namevec1," ")
  temp2<-strsplit(namevec2," ")
  ifelse(is.na(charmatch(temp1,temp2)),F,T)
}

namevec1<-c("ffd","ff","hello_world")
namevec2<-c("ffde","ff ","hello_wor")
```

> namevec1 %inlike% namevec2

[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

> namevec2 %inlike% namevec1

[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

(please note the white space difference)